# RegionPlot with Assumptions

Tags: plotting, regions

I am trying to evaluate the properties of a multivariate function $f(a,b,x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ given assumptions for $a$ and $b$.

An example without $a$ and $b$.

```
RegionPlot[{x*y > 0, x*y < 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

How can I include that for example $a > 0$ and $b < 0$ for $a\,b\,x\,y$? The ultimate goal is to evaluate the sign for $f(a,b,x,y)$ given a set of parameters $a$ and $b$.

I have tried `Plot`, `RegionPlot`, `Plot[Sign[...]]`, etc., without success.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to plot for the condition $a>0$.  Do you want $f(.1, b, x, y)$, $f(.2, b, x, y)$, and so on for an infinite number of graphs?  Also, please eliminate extraneous code that is irrelevant to your question (viz. `PlotLegends`).

Comment: I want a two-dimensional graph for (x,y) whose effects are most important but (a,b) are parameters with any positive or negative values that can be kept constant for evaluation. 

I could set specific values for (a,b) as examples but I would prefer a general discussion of (x,y)-effects.

Comment: What can you possibly mean--rigorously, mathematically--by "most important"?  How can you possibly get a "general discussion..."?  Show us one concrete example (done by hand, if necessary).  Also, please edit your question to eliminate irrelevant code, as I suggested before.

Comment: A simple example would be an output function with multiple inputs. All inputs have an effect on output but I am mostly interested in the effects of, say, capital or labor. However, whether the effects are positive or negative may depend on the specific values of other inputs - why I want to keep their exact values unspecified.

Comment: Your "example" is far too vague.  Please write an equation involving $a,b,x,f$ and what you seek.  I've given a possible answer using `Manipulate` but you are too vague about what you're seeking.  Don't talk about capital or labor.  Give equations!

Comment: Thanks for the manipulate example. A mathematical example: f(a,b,x,y) = a*x*y - b. Assumptions could be 0<a<1, 0<x<1, 0<y<1 and 0<b<0.5. I would like then to know when f(.) is positive/negative/zero/depends.

Comment: `Manipulate[RegionPlot[{a x y - b > 0, a x y + b < 0}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}],
 {{a, .5}, 0, 1}, {{b, .25}, 0, .5}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you asked for:

```
Manipulate[
  RegionPlot[a x y - b > 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
  {{a, .5}, 0, 1}, {{b, .25}, 0, .5}]
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a possibility to specify that 0<b<a -- e.g., a>0, b>0 and b<a?

Comment: Certainly:  `Manipulate[RegionPlot[a x y - b > 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}], {{a, .5}, 0, 1}, {{b, .25}, 0, a}]`.  I urge you to read the documentation on `Manipulate`, which describes all these concepts clearly.

Comment: My apologies for the misunderstanding. The question was regarding RegionPlot without using Manipulate and allowing a, b to be greater than 1.

Comment: Now I have no idea what you want, as I stated in my first comment (above).

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what the aim is here. I post this to illustrate shading approaches in case it may be helpful. Shading by sign of function:

```
fun[f_] := 
 Row[{ContourPlot[ Sign[f], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    Contours -> {-1, 1}, ContourShading -> {Red, Blue}, 
    ImageSize -> 300],
   Plot3D[f, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, MeshFunctions -> (Sign@#3 &), 
    MeshShading -> {Blue, Red}, ImageSize -> 300]}]
```

Examples:

```
Manipulate[
 fun[test], {test, {Sin[x y], Sin[x + y], Sin[x - y], Cos[x y], x y, 
   x + y, x - y}}]
```

[image]

Obviously, you can use manipulate for parameter tuning  `a` and `b`.